# Notifications Center Alternate in MAC OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, notifications, growl

I have an application that fires notification 5-6 times a day on some specific times set by users. Right now I'm using Notification Center fo scheduling of notifications but unfortunately it's supported only in Mac OS X 10.8. Actually, I want my app available for the users of MAC OS X 10.6 too. For that I searched the internet and found a third party app GROWL. But here the problem is, if I use Growl, 1st it requires users to install it to get notifications from apps. 2nd and main problem is I dont think there is any functionality in GROWL to schedule notifications on particular time just like we have in Notifications Center to schedule by giving fireDate.

```
+[GrowlApplicationBridge
notifyWithTitle:(NSString *)title
description:(NSString *)description
notificationName:(NSString *)notificationName
iconData:(NSData *)iconData
priority:(signed int)priority
isSticky:(BOOL)isSticky
clickContext:(id)clickContext]
```

theres nothing to fire on a particular time in GROWL, can you please guide me to the right path ? how this can be done in 10.6 ??

Comment: Well I'm using NSTimer that will call a selector after every second to keep track of the time and checks whether notification time arrived or not. But I dont think its a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm using NSTimer that will call a selector after every second to keep track of the time and checks whether notification time arrived or not. But I dont think its a good practice.